# Как клиенту отдавать класс А, содержащий weak_ptr, а в библиотеке использовать класс А с shared_ptr без дублирования кода?

Tags: c++, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Начну с наивных реализаций, чтобы подвести к сути вопроса. Допустим есть первая реализация двух классов. Думаю, тут задача понятна

```
class A
{
    string name_{};
public:
    A(string_view name): name_(name) {};
};

class B
{
    vector<A*> v_{}; // ВАРИАНТ 1
public:
    B() {};
    ~B() { for (auto& a : v_) delete a; };

    A* createA(string_view name) 
    { 
        v_.push_back(new A(name));
        return v_.back(); 
    }
};
```

Но отдавать клиенту сырые указатели плохо, поэтому следующий шаг - используем std::shared_ptr для хранения объектов класса A

```
class A
{
    string name_{};
public:
    A(string_view name) : name_(name) {};
};

class B
{
    vector<shared_ptr<A>> v_{}; // ВАРИАНТ 2
public:
    B() {};

    shared_ptr<A> createA(string_view name) 
    { 
        v_.push_back(make_shared<A>(name)); 
        return v_.back(); 
    }
};
```

Следующая наивная итерация - скрываем реализацию используя идиому PImpl

```
class A
{
    struct Impl;
    shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl; // СЛЕДУЮЩАЯ ИТЕРАЦИЯ
public:
    A(string_view name) /* : pImpl(make_shared<Impl>()) */ { };
    /*public API*/
};

class B
{
    vector<A> v_{};
public:
    B() {};

    A createA(string_view name)
    {
        v_.emplace_back(name);
        return v_.back();
    }
};
```

Теперь клиенту отдается объекты класса А, которые содержат shared_ptr на реализацию, которая скрыта от клиента.

Я ищу способ сделать еще одну итерацию данного процесса разработки. Дело в том, что в приложении будет намного больше двух классов, которые будут выстраиваться в древовидные структуры. Т.к. класс shared_ptr позволяет подсчитывать количество ссылок, хотелось бы использовать эту возможность. Но количество объектов, созданных клиентом меня не интересует, хотелось бы вести подсчет ссылок только в библиотеке. Т.е. хотелось бы клиенту отдавать класс А, содержащий weak_ptr, а в библиотеке использовать класс А с shared_ptr...
Как я не пыталась реализовать - получается много дублирующего кода для поддержки двух видов класса А.
Есть ли решение этой задачи на данном пути? Или же надо использовать какой либо другой паттерн проектирования?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138873/discussion-on-question-by-milla-------weak-pt).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - возможно будет проще во 2 варианте всегда возвращать weak_ptr для всех - и для библиотеки и для клиента? Доступа к объекту через weak_ptr нет, для доступа необходимо его преобразовывать в `shared_ptr`.

```
class B
{
    vector<shared_ptr<A>> v_{}; // ВАРИАНТ 2
public:
    weak_ptr<A> createA(string_view name) 
    { 
        v_.push_back(make_shared<A>(name)); 
        return weak_ptr<A> tmp( v_.back() ); 
    }
};
```

Или по той же причине в `class A` хранить `weak_ptr`. Когда библиотеке понадобиться - она преобразует в `shared_ptr` и счетчик увеличится. Но на мой взгляд делать обертку над оберткой - просто усложнение кода, т.к. `shared_ptr` (в комплекте с `weak_ptr`) - уже обертка над объектом, определяющая его время жизни.

Или сделать 2 фабричные функции - одну для библиотеки (не видна клиенту), вторую - для клиента

```
class B
{
    vector<shared_ptr<A>> v_{}; // ВАРИАНТ 2
    shared_ptr<A> createA(string_view name) // фабричная функция для библиотеки, недоступная клиенту
    { 
        v_.push_back(make_shared<A>(name)); 
        return v_.back(); 
    }
public:
    weak_ptr<A> GetA(string_view name) // фабричная функция для клиента
    { 
        return weak_ptr<A> tmp( createA(name) ); 
    }
};
```

И непонятно, как клиент использует данные объекта и вообще использует ли? Если использует, то ему всё равно нужно преобразовывать `weak_ptr` в `shared_ptr` - а это увеличит счетчик ссылок.

> Но количество объектов, созданных клиентом меня не интересует,
> хотелось бы вести подсчет ссылок только в библиотеке.

Т.е. клиент может создавать объекты минуя `class B::createA()`? Это точно? Тогда у библиотеки и клиента получается два разных пула объектов и в каком-то месте нужно отдать клиенту копию объекта из библиотеки (`shared_ptr` на копию объекта) а не указатель на сам объект.  Это точно то поведение, которого вы хотите добиться?

Comment: сейчас примерно так и реализовано. Хранится все в vector<shared_ptr<A>>. Все внутренние связи пишутся через shared_ptr, Клиенту (например, GUI) выдается weak_ptr (если выдавать shared_ptr, то нельзя понять, это GUI наплодил элементов, или это внутренняя структура). Но тут несколько минусов

Comment: Ну вы клиенту выдали weak_ptr. Если клиент начинает работать с объектом, он из weak_ptr делает shared_ptr и счетчики увеличиваются.

Comment: "Т.е. клиент может создавать объекты минуя class B::createA()? ", нет, создавать может только через данный интерфейс, но потом накопировать эти элементы у себя, и сколько именно, меня не интересует. Но тут несколько минусов. Раскрытие реализации, вынуждаю клиента вызывать weak_ptr.lock(), клиент наплодит shared_ptr из weak_ptr и т.п

Comment: поэтому и не хочется выдавать weak_ptr, а сделать обертку

Comment: В обертке вы всё равно используете weak_ptr или shared_ptr. Просто клиенту нужно отдать сразу копию объекта (shared_ptr на копию), раз вы говорите, что он может копировать объекты сколько угодно. Или в классе-фабрике (class B) использовать собственный подсчет ссылок, а не пользоваться встроенным в библиотечные шаблоны shared_ptr.

Comment: Или сделайте 2 обертки, но являющиеся наследниками одного виртуального класса. Таким образом получите одинаковый интерфейс для работы, избежите дублирования кода и сможете реализовать раздельный подсчет ссылок для библиотеки и клиента.